# React Mui Appbar theming

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, appbar, themeprovider

I tried theming MUI AppBar but I have no idea about theming.
Can I style an AppBar with theme without using styled component or other style api?

**palette.js**

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: "#000F04"
        }
    }
});
```

**App.js**

```
import theme from "../../styles/palette";
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <AppBar position="static" color="primary">
        <Toolbar>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

Comment: yes, you can provide multi and custom ThemeProvider and wrap them at the same time to use in your application.

Comment: but that code doesn't work..

Comment: which code not working? what is the error? please explain more about it or provide more code snippets to help.

Comment: I expected Appbar color change to "#000F04" but it's "#1976d2" which is the default main color in the [default theme object](https://mui.com/customization/default-theme/).
Is this the right way to style Mui components?

Comment: It works fine in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/buttonappbar-material-demo-forked-e0voq?file=/demo.js)

Comment: please update your question with the above code snippet, thanks.

Comment: It works! I should have to import from the same package.
I imported AppBar from '@material-ui/core' and imported ThemeProvider from '@mui/material/styles', thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your codesandbox work.

Use the `sx` props if you need to add specific style.  https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/

You can too overide style on the theme: https://mui.com/customization/theme-components/#heading-global-style-overrides